# How to move question from on stack exchange to another.

Tags: discussion

I have a bernoulli function question on stack overflow that nobody seems to answer and I think it best that I move it math.SE because they are better suited to answer my question.

But how to I move it? Does a moderator have privileges like such?

When somebody does move it if they can, which account MATH.SE or Stack Overflow is the question registered it or better explained by which account gets upvotes after they move my question?

Comment: More info - the question doesn't contain code or even ask for code, instead I asked for a mathematical equation/function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the question is off topic on the current site, I doubt a migration would be justified; there are a lot of sites which overlap each other in terms of what's on topic and yet we don't see questions being migrated all over the place, that would only make unnecessary work for moderators.

If you're certain the question is off topic currently (it would most likely be on hold), you can flag it for moderator attention and ask for a migration there.

I recommend you put a bounty on the question instead to draw more attention to it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this to me. I will flag it for moderator attention.